# Is the coequalizer of two abelian groups in Ab the same as their coequalizer in Set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $F: \bf{Ab} \to \bf{Set}$ be the forgetful functor. Does F preserve coequalizers for all pairs of morphisms? (not just F-split pairs)

Let me restate my question. Let $f,g :G_1 \to G_2$ be any abelian group homomorphisms. Consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $G_2$ generated by $f(x)\sim g(x)$ for all $x \in G_1$. Does the following always hold

$x \sim y \iff x -y \in Im(f-g)$,

or do we need the splitting condition (Barr-Beck)? If this is true I suppose that it's also true for the forgetful functors on $\bf{Grp}$ and $\bf{Vect}$. I know that it's not true in general for the forgetful functor on the category of torsion-free abelian groups, as the coequalizer in $\bf{TFAb}$ imposes more relations on the quotient. Could we characterise those categories for which this is true? (if it is true at all).

Comment: It is not true. You can find a counterexample where $g = 0$ and the groups are finite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the (somewhat generic) case of an element $a \in G$ of an abelian group $G$, seen as a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to G$, $z \mapsto za$, paired with the trivial homomorphism $0 : \mathbb{Z} \to G$, $z \mapsto 0$. The equivalence relation generated by $za \sim 0$ can be described as follows: We have $g \sim g'$ iff $g=g'$ or $g,g' \in \langle a \rangle$. This is clearly much stronger than $g-g' \in \langle a \rangle$.

Apart from [reflexive coequalizers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflexive+coequalizer), there are "almost no" coequalizers preserved by $\mathbf{Ab} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! I think you mean $g-g' \in \langle a \rangle$ does not necessarily imply $g = g'$ or $g,g' \in \langle a \rangle$, and not the other way around.

Comment: I want to point out that there is an important class of coequalisers that is preserved: namely, reflexive coequalisers. This is essentially because $\textbf{Ab}$ is a Mal'cev category and $\textbf{Ab} \to \textbf{Set}$ is exact in the sense of Barr.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, every finitary monad on $\mathbf{Set}$ preserves reflexive coequalizers, hence the forgetful functor from its algebras preserves them as well. See also https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflexive+coequalizer